# How to apply both horizontal and vertical scroll in `DataTable` using `SingleChildScrollView` widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a data table that it horizontally and vertically exceeds screen size and I need to use both vertical and horizontal scroll. 
I used this code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Vis_Code')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Vis_Name')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('ID_Voucher')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Voucher_Type_Title')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Stock_Title')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Date_Voucher')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Customer_Name')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Good_Title')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Meghdar_F')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Price_Kol_F')),
      ],
      rows:
          littlevouchers element
              .map(
                ((element) => DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text(element["Vis_Code"])), 
                    DataCell(Text(element["Vis_Name"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["ID_Voucher"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Voucher_Type_Title"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Stock_Title"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Date_Voucher"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Customer_Name"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Good_Title"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Meghdar_F"])),
                    DataCell(Text(element["Price_Kol_F"])),
                  ],
                )),
              )
              .toList(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

But flutter just applied horizontal scroll.

In addition, the DataTable overflowed the bottom of screen. and raises below error:

`A RenderFlex overflowed by 30 pixels on the bottom.`

Do you have any idea?

Comment: it works with my example... If you want us to give you more help please amend your code in your question where we can duplicate the error by copy and paste the code

Comment: You mean it works properly in your system ?

Comment: Yes... I had no problem with it

Comment: It's really weird. Maybe the issue is related to my data source! Let me check.

Comment: try it and if it will not work then create reproducible code for us to duplicate the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was wrapped by `Column` widget. I removed it and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it is working you can replace the image widget with your widgets:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Image.asset("assets/Home.jpeg",)
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing works also

```
          class ScrollViewWidget extends BaseWidget {

    const ScrollViewWidget( {
      super.key,
      required this.children,
      this.isScrollable,
      this.mainAxisAlignment,
      this.mainAxisSize,
      this.padding,
      this.scrollContoller,
    } );

    final List<Widget> children;
    final bool? isScrollable;
    final MainAxisAlignment? mainAxisAlignment;
    final MainAxisSize? mainAxisSize;
    final EdgeInsetsGeometry? padding;
    final ScrollController? scrollContoller;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scrollbar (
          controller: scrollContoller,
          thickness: 10,
          trackVisibility: true, //showTrackOnHover: true,
          thumbVisibility: true, //isAlwaysShown: true,
          child: SingleChildScrollView (
            //primary: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: isScrollable ?? true ? const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: SizedBox (
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              //height: ,
              child: Padding (
                padding: padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Column (
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment ?? MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize ?? MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: children,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
    } 
  }
```