# Vertical & Horizontal Scroll Not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

### Problem Description

I am trying to create a horizontal and vertical to a single child widget with flutter simple tree view package. But I am not sure why:

1. The horizontal scroll can't be scroll, its like stuck on it initial position
2. The vertical scrollbar not showing up

I tried to change the `Expanded` Widget to `SizedBox` but still not working.

### My Output

[image]

- horizontal scrollbar not working.
- vertical scrollbar not showing although setup `thumbVisibility` to true.

### Expected Output

[image: Flutter Devtools]

### To Reproduce

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_simple_treeview/flutter_simple_treeview.dart';

class HorizontalVerticalScroll extends StatelessWidget {
  HorizontalVerticalScroll({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          child: Expanded(
            child: Scrollbar(
              thumbVisibility: true,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Scrollbar(
                  thumbVisibility: true,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: TreeView(nodes: [
                        TreeNode(content: Text("root1")),
                        TreeNode(
                          content: Text("root2"),
                          children: [
                            TreeNode(content: Text("child21")),
                            TreeNode(content: Text("child22")),
                            TreeNode(
                              content: Text("root23"),
                              children: [
                                TreeNode(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "child231111111111111111111111111111111119999999999999999"),
                                    children: [
                                      TreeNode(
                                        content: Text(
                                            "child231111111111111111111111111111111119999999999999999"),
                                      )
                                    ]),
                                TreeNode(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "child231111111111111111111111111111111119999999999999999")),
                                TreeNode(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "child231111111111111111111111111111111119999999999999999")),
                                TreeNode(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "child231111111111111111111111111111111119999999999999999")),
                                TreeNode(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "child231111111111111111111111111111111119999999999999999")),
                              ],
                            ),
                            TreeNode(
                              content: Text("root23"),
                              children: [
                                TreeNode(content: Text("child231")),
                              ],
                            ),
                            TreeNode(
                              content: Text("root23"),
                              children: [
                                TreeNode(content: Text("child231")),
                              ],
                            ),
                            TreeNode(
                              content: Text("root23"),
                              children: [
                                TreeNode(content: Text("child231")),
                              ],
                            ),
                            TreeNode(
                              content: Text("root23"),
                              children: [
                                TreeNode(content: Text("child231")),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### References Stack Overflow:

1. [How to apply both horizontal and vertical scroll in `DataTable` using `SingleChildScrollView` widget in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155514/how-to-apply-both-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-in-datatable-using-singlechi)
2. [Flutter Scrollbar in vertical and horizontal axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819986/flutter-scrollbar-in-vertical-and-horizontal-axis)